# Html does no update on ipage

Tags: html

I host a small website for my company of the hosting service called Ipage. I use the on website editor to edit my code. When ever I make edits to my HTML or CSS it does not update on the site. I have tried editing the .htdocs file to stop cache but I didn't seem to work. I am open to anything!

Thanks!

Comment: contact the support staff of "ipage"

Comment: glad I saw this because I had the same issue just needed to see the answer and where to go thanks Oak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right on the sense that I does have somthing to do with the cache, but you where wrong in editing the .htdocs file. Ipage uses a cache system that will make the website faster when you have multiple users on it at the same time. This was commonly a problem so Ipage made a little tool for you! http://www.ipage.com/controlpanel/cachecontrol/ That is a link to the page that will allow you to turn of all the cache on your serve.